# if statement not working properly regarding return value- PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to solve this problem for several days but still unable to. I'm trying to do an if statement using `mysqli_num_rows($result)>0` but it wont work properly. This sounds weird. If `result>0`, it will display records (which is working fine) else no record would be displayed (which is also working fine) but the table keeps showing. I don't know why(the table not suppose to appear if result returned empty).The other related problem is, when there is no record, 3 value seems to appear  (no image value under column picture, date under column `Dat Reg`, delete under column Terminate Membership). Any help would be appreciated.I can't get "no image value", "date" and "delete" to go away when result return empty. I'm trying to make the entire table not to appear so that the columns (would also not show but it can't work).

**userpage.php**

```
<p align="left">A. YOUR RECORDS </p>
<p align="left">
<?php
echo "<tr><td></tr></td>";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=0 id='secondtable'>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Membership"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Title"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Location"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Phone"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Picture"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Date Reg"."</td>".
"<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>"."Terminate Membership?"."</td></tr>";
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
while( $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$showdateua=$row['dateua'];
$showdateua=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($showdateua));
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['Membership']=$row['Membership'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['Title']=$row['Title'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['location']=$row['location'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['adphone']=$row['adphone'].
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".
'<img src="'.$_SESSION['image1']=$row['image1'].'"alt="No image"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>'.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>".$_SESSION['dateua']=$showdateua.
"</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>"."<a href=\"rundelup.php?idadv=".$row['idadv']."\">"."Delete"."</a></td></tr>";
}
}
echo "</table>";}
else
{
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)===0)
{echo "No records";}
}?>
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
if (isset($result)){
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
echo "<table>";
$page=(int)$page;
if($page>$tpages)
{$page=$tpages;}
if($page<1)
{$page=1;
}
if($page==1){
echo "";}
else
{
//go to first page 
echo "<tr><td><a href='?page=1'class='button'>FIRST</a></td>";
}
if($page>1)
{
//go to previous page to show previous 3 items. 
echo "<td><a href='?page=".($page-1)."'class='button'><<</a></td>";
}
echo "<ul class='page'>";
for($i=max($page-4,1);$i<=max(1,min($tpages,$page+4));$i++)
{
if($i==$page){
echo "<td><class='current'>".$i."</td>";
}
else{
echo "<td><a href='?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></td>";}
//echo "<tr><td><a href=useradacc.php?page=".$i.">".$i."</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</ul>";
if($page!=$tpages)
{
//go to next page to show next 3 items. 
echo "<td><a href='?page=".($page+1)."'class='button'>>></a></td>";
}
if($page==$tpages)
{
    echo "";}
    else{
//go to last page 
echo "<td><a href='?page=".($page=$tpages)."'class='button'>LAST</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
}}
else
{echo "Insert record";
}
?>
```

**include file (run.php)**

```
<?php
if(isset($conn)){
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
//pagination calculation
$reclimit=3;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page=$_GET['page'];}
else
{
$page=1;
}
$start=(($page-1)*$reclimit);
$advert = "SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN uaddd ua ON  u.id=ua.id
WHERE u.id='".$id."'";
$result=$conn->query($advert);
$total=$result->num_rows;
$tpages=ceil($total/$reclimit);
//pagination script ends here
$advert = "SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN uaddd ua ON  u.id=ua.id
WHERE u.id='".$id."'ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT $start,$reclimit";
$statement = $conn->prepare($advert);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result(); }
if ($conn->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: ".$conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Comment: You are mixing both procedural and OO mysqli style

Comment: Tks for the reply @Chay22. noted....I thought both could mix..?hehehe.....thanks for the tip..

Comment: I'll give it a try first.. coz it's hard to differentiate between procedural and OO mysqli style..to me it looks all the same..

Comment: @Chay22. I did what u suggest.. but still same...?any hopes?

Comment: it was just a simple notice, though. You can't do prepared statement on `$statement` like that. Use `$conn->query()` instead and fetch result with `$conn->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: still the same issue...@Chay22. Not sure why the three plus the table wont dissapear..:-(

Comment: see my answer below @kmaJJ

Answer (score 0):

There may be another error on your code.
Make sure you got a working SQL query by looking the output of it.

```
$advert = "SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN uaddd ua ON u.id=ua.id WHERE u.id='".$id."'ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT $start,$reclimit";
$statement = $conn->query($advert);
var_dump($statement);
```

See a result?

---

**Prepared statement**
uses `?` sign for dynamic parameters and bind its variable outside sql query using `bind_param()`.

```
$stmt= $conn->prepare("SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN uaddd ua ON  u.id=ua.id WHERE u.id= ? ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT ?,?");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $id, $start, $reclimit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

You can fetch the result afterwards

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   var_dump($row);
}
```

*Make sure you know type of variable you are going to bind*

> ***i***  = corresponding variable has type integer
>
> ***d***  = corresponding variable has type double
>
> ***s***  = corresponding variable has type string
>
> ***b***  = corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

From http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Or using just using `mysqli::query`

```
$stmt= $conn->query("SELECT u.*,ua.* FROM uskkk u LEFT JOIN uaddd ua ON u.id=ua.id WHERE u.id='".$id."'ORDER BY dateua DESC LIMIT $start,$reclimit");
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
   var_dump($row);
}
```

---

Change the table structure like this

```
echo "<table cellpadding=10 border=0 id='secondtable'>";
echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Membership" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Title" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Location" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Phone" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Picture" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Date Reg" . "</td>" . "<td bgcolor=#698C00 class='white'>" . "Terminate Membership?" . "</td></tr>";
 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $showdateua = $row['dateua'];
     $showdateua = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($showdateua));
     echo "<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . $_SESSION['Membership'] = $row['Membership'] . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . $_SESSION['Title'] = $row['Title'] . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . $_SESSION['location'] = $row['location'] . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . $_SESSION['adphone'] = $row['adphone'] . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . '<img src="' . $_SESSION['image1'] = $row['image1'] . '"alt="No image"style="width:100px;height:100px;"/>' . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . $_SESSION['dateua'] = $showdateua . "</td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC>" . "<a href=\"rundelup.php?idadv=" . $row['idadv'] . "\">" . "Delete" . "</a></td></tr>";
   }
} else {
  echo "No records";
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hi@Chay22. Tqs. there is some development here. But now i got an error "Call to a member function get_result() on a non-object .....on line 38 "which refers to "$stmt->bind_param("iii", $id, $start, $reclimit);".

Comment: @kmaJJ Is your variable `$id` type of integer? Or the error may be coming from sql syntax, I guess.

Comment: i tried the latest option that u gave me above.  no errors prompted.. ..but the three text which i mentioned earlier "no image value", "date" and "delete" still appears. I cleared the DB already. :-(

Comment: If result>0, the records appear. else it disappears (working fine) but i just cant get the 3 text to disappear when result>0. Even when I cleared the DB, it keeps showing. Is my script or arrangement of codes that terrible?.

Comment: What kind of text? I can't understand. Anyways, you are overwriting your sessions since you set it up inside loop